# Jenkins - how to publish robotframework report without plugin

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

Due to server machine problem, I am not able to install robotframework jenkins plugin.

Any workaround to publish test report at jenkins?

I have tried to do post build html report but nothing was publish after test run.

**configuration:**
[image]

latest status: after build completed, click on HTML report, the background loaded only, no content.
http://jenkinsserver:8080/job/test/17/HTMLReport/
[image]

Download the ZIP - I can see all files exported to Jenkins server job folder correctly.
[image]

at jenkins server, I can see the report at this path

```
file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Jenkins/jobs/test/builds/17/htmlreports/HTMLReport/report.html
```

[image]

Comment: You could save test results as xunit and use another plugin to show test trends. You can also save robot output files as artifacts so those interested can view details.

Comment: the jenkins server is unable to install any plugins. so I am looking for the solution to works with default jenkins HTML report. updated main post with more details and latest status.